# Build from source error: missing input file 'external/net_sf_jchart2d/jar/jchart2d.jar'

Tags: drake

I try to build drake1.0.0 from source using bazel. However I encounter the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/chenwang/drake-build/_bazel_chenwang/bcff9e14963ec4b6ed21d9b7e9e180fc/external/net_sf_jchart2d/jar/BUILD.bazel:2:12: Extracting interface @net_sf_jchart2d//jar:jar failed: missing input file 'external/net_sf_jchart2d/jar/jchart2d.jar', owner: '@net_sf_jchart2d//jar:jchart2d.jar'
ERROR: /home/chenwang/drake-build/_bazel_chenwang/bcff9e14963ec4b6ed21d9b7e9e180fc/external/net_sf_jchart2d/jar/BUILD.bazel:2:12: Extracting interface @net_sf_jchart2d//jar:jar failed: 1 input file(s) do not exist
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/chenwang/drake-build/_bazel_chenwang/bcff9e14963ec4b6ed21d9b7e9e180fc/external/net_sf_jchart2d/jar/BUILD.bazel:2:12 Extracting interface @net_sf_jchart2d//jar:jar failed: 1 input file(s) do not exist
INFO: Elapsed time: 23.087s, Critical Path: 8.22s
INFO: 2890 processes: 2584 internal, 306 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'drake_cxx_python-prefix/src/drake_cxx_python-stamp/drake_cxx_python-build' failed
make[2]: *** [drake_cxx_python-prefix/src/drake_cxx_python-stamp/drake_cxx_python-build] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:931: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have built older version drake from source successfully. It seems that I miss some third-party library for building the new version drake. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you confirm that you have rerun the `install_repreqs.sh` script since you updated?

Comment: Thank you very much @RussTedrake! I forget to rerun the `install_repreqs.sh` after updating. After reruning it, I can build from source successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the `install_repreqs.sh` has been updated and I forget to rerun it. After installing the prerequisite by rerunning `install_repreqs.sh`, I can build drake from source successfully.